# Will my WPA2 device be able to make use of WPA3 features?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wpa2

A few days ago, the Wi-Fi Alliance [released](https://www.wi-fi.org/news-events/newsroom/wi-fi-alliance-introduces-security-enhancements) WPA3, a new security standard which will replace WPA2.

My question is, will it be possible for my existing devices to make use of WPA3 features (see [this](https://www.wired.com/story/wpa3-wi-fi-security-passwords-easy-connect/) and [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/339765/what-is-wpa3-and-when-will-i-get-it-on-my-wi-fi/)) through a software/firmware upgrade from the device vendor/manufacturer?